How can ensure a section of code is executed right after Authentication in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?
I am using ASP.NET Core 8 Identity I would like to execute some code that ensures that the current user who has just logged in has specified the time zone they wish to use. If not, I want to redirect them to a page that asks for their time zone. If they do not specify their time zone, they should not be authenticated to use the application.
At first, I thought of just executing this code in a Razor Page code behind method and redirecting to that page upon authentication, but that means that all a user has to do it just type in the correct URL, and they are free to use the app normally.
How can I execute these checks after authenticating a user, while withholding their authentication status until they complete this task of specifying their time zone?

I have implement this feature by using middleware, you can check the detailed steps below.
1. Create a TimeZoneMiddleware.cs file and register it.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using TimeZoneApp.Data;

namespace TimeZoneApp
{
    public class TimeZoneMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public TimeZoneMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (!context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/TimeZoneApp")))
                {
                    var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);
                    if (user != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.TimeZone))
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/TimeZoneApp");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

2. Register it
...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
// add it here
app.UseMiddleware<TimeZoneMiddleware>();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

3. My test Page
@page
@model TimeZoneApp.Pages.SetTimeZoneModel

<h2>Set Your Time Zone</h2>

<form method="post">
    <label for="timezone">Time Zone:</label>
    <select asp-for="UserTimeZone" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select a time zone</option>
        <option value="UTC-05:00">Eastern Time (US & Canada)</option>
        <option value="UTC-08:00">Pacific Time (US & Canada)</option>
        <!-- Add more time zones as needed -->
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Set Time Zone</button>
</form>



using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using TimeZoneApp.Data;

namespace TimeZoneApp.Pages
{
    [Authorize]
    public class SetTimeZoneModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public SetTimeZoneModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public string UserTimeZone { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user != null)
            {
                user.TimeZone = UserTimeZone;
                var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("/Index");
                }
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}

4. ApplicationUser.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace TimeZoneApp.Data
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string? TimeZone { get; set; }
    }

}

